# Solidity : submit string array, key value pair or an object as parameter to a function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

In order to change the state of the smart contract from front end inputs, wanted to submit string array to a smart contract , key value pair or objects.

Is it possible to use string array as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

No solidity doesn't support arrays of strings as parameter. You would have to serialize and deserialize it in a string yourself to have the desired result but that would be expensive to do in solidity. You can test that on remix if you want. However, on remix the error message says that this function is supported in the `experimental ABI encoder` but I have never tested that, or how well it works with other libraries, and it is experimental after all.

Comment: Have tried with "experimental ABI encoder" earlier and that works fine on remix, but was looking production release lib. Any alternative for the same to work around.

Comment: No, besides serializing and deserializing the array yourself I haven't found anything reliable. Although if you don't plan on manipulating the array on the contract and you are just looking to store it there and retrieve it I think that you can just stringify it, store it, and then retrieve it and parse it. But the gas cost for this could be high if you have a lot of data to store. If you plan on storing a lot of data you could look into `IPFS` for storage, it goes well with the blockchain too.

Comment: any particular links or samples to work upon with IPFS with ethereum that would appreciate.

Comment: These 2 links can probably get you started: 
https://medium.com/@didil/off-chain-data-storage-ethereum-ipfs-570e030432cf  
https://itnext.io/build-a-simple-ethereum-interplanetary-file-system-ipfs-react-js-dapp-23ff4914ce4e
The basic idea is that you store data on IPFS and then you store the hashes you get on the contract. Also besides their javascript library, IPFS offers an HTTP API you can use if you can't use the js package: https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/http/

Answer (score 0):

As seen in below example from solidity document we can send bytes array to constructor

```
constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) public {
    chairperson = msg.sender;
    voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

    // For each of the provided proposal names,
    // create a new proposal object and add it
    // to the end of the array.
    for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
        // `Proposal({...})` creates a temporary
        // Proposal object and `proposals.push(...)`
        // appends it to the end of `proposals`.
        proposals.push(Proposal({
            name: proposalNames[i],
            voteCount: 0
        }));
    }
}
```

If you are trying to send string/Objects data specifically then it's better to separate out the methods and call each methods separately or within each other as currently solidity does not support that (using ABIencodere v2 is exceptional as it is only recommended for development purpose- as per on the date of this answer written)

```
struct A{
uint date,
B[] b
}
```

You can separate this out to

```
struct A{
uint date
}
struct B{
string goods,
uint quantity
}
```

so now for 1 A you can call N B from your service. Use mapping for binding both(if dependent).

**In current situation it's better to design a contract which does not take bulk inputs or give out bulk outputs. However contracts are not for storage of huge data it's for storage of related data which fulfills agreement between parties**